# ros::init API Documentation

Tags: ros, roscpp, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble finding the `ros::init` call in the documentation. I've followed a few of the tutorial links and tried searching through the documentation. Here are my main leads:

http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/index.html

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown -- The links here 404

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129116/ros::init-api-documentation/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2014-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2014-02-13**:
I looked through the header and saw that my second link pretty much describes all of the init functionality. So I guess my question is just related to navigating the doxygen documentation ... am I doing it wrong or is ros::init really not in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/init_8h.html

But I don't know why it doesn't appear in the API doc under the same url as before. It seems like doxygen is not correctly referencing any symbols in the ros namespace.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2014-02-13**:
Perfect! I like all functions laid out. I didn't think to check each header individually. I was hoping it would be under the namespace section or functions sections but nope. Thank you!